# How to control the download speed in browser?

Tags: linux, tcp, traffic

With parameter  `--limit-rate=80k`, downloading speed with wget can be limited in 80k/s.

```
url="http://caesar.acc.umu.se/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-8.7.1-amd64-CD-1.iso";
wget --limit-rate=80k -c $url -O /tmp/debian.iso
```

Now I want to control the download speed within 80k/s too in firefox. How to set a limit?

[image]

Can iptable or tc do the task?

Answer (score 3):

use [trickle](https://github.com/mariusae/trickle)

```
trickle -d 80 firefox
```

or use [flashgot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashgot/), which can download files with `wget`.